# Tracking down the source of java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java

I have a Java applet which sometimes throws a java.security.AccessControlException whenever I call File.exists(). The problem goes away whenever I enclose the operation in an AccessController.doPrivileged() block. However, I can't figure out why. My applet is signed and should be fully trusted. In other scenarios, it can read/write to files without any problems.

Is there a way to walk up my calling stack and examine the effective permissions so that I can see who or what is trusted/untrusted?

Comment: You should look for source of `file.exists()` rather than `java.security.AccessControlException` cause there you can see where exactly the exception is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable [java.security.debug property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/debugger.html#jsdp) with `access:stack` first. It will help you understand what permission is lacking to the domain.